# Android Emulator is not started through Jenkins

Tags: android, android-studio, jenkins, android-emulator

I am trying to set up my mobile automation pack in Jenkins. As a first step, when I try to launch a emulator using Jenkins Android Emulator plugin, I am getting below error

Job Config

[image]

Android SDK details

[image]

[image]

Below is the error

```
$ C:\Users\Divakar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe start-server
[android] Snapshots are enabled, but cannot be used as they are not supported by the current SDK Tools
[android] Starting Android emulator
[android] Erasing existing emulator data...
$ C:\Users\Divakar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/emulator/emulator.exe -ports 5764,5765 -report-console tcp:5850,max=60 -avd Pixel_2_Pie_9.0 -wipe-data -no-window
Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
dsound: Could not set cooperative level for window 0000000000000000
dsound: Reason: An invalid parameter was passed to the returning function
audio: Could not init `dsound' audio driver
emulator: WARNING: Requested adb port (5765) is outside the recommended range [5555,5586]. ADB may not function properly for the emulator. See -help-port for details.
[android] Emulator reported that the console is available on port 5,764
[android] Waiting for emulator to finish booting...
$ C:\Users\Divakar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe -s emulator-5764 wait-for-device shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
ERROR: Timeout after 90000 milliseconds
$ C:\Users\Divakar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe -s emulator-5764 wait-for-device shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
emulator: INFO: boot completed
emulator: Increasing screen off timeout, logcat buffer size to 2M.
emulator: Revoking microphone permissions for Google App.
ERROR: Timeout after 90000 milliseconds
$ C:\Users\Divakar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe -s emulator-5764 wait-for-device shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
ERROR: Timeout after 90000 milliseconds
$ C:\Users\Divakar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe -s emulator-5764 wait-for-device shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
ERROR: Timeout after 90000 milliseconds
$ C:\Users\Divakar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe -s emulator-5764 wait-for-device shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
ERROR: Timeout after 90000 milliseconds
$ C:\Users\Divakar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe -s emulator-5764 wait-for-device shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
ERROR: Timeout after 90000 milliseconds
$ C:\Users\Divakar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe -s emulator-5764 wait-for-device shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
ERROR: Timeout after 90000 milliseconds
[android] Timed-out after waiting 720 seconds for emulator
[android] Stopping Android emulator
$ C:\Users\Divakar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe kill-server
emulator: Saving state on exit with session uptime 730379 ms
Finished: NOT_BUILT
```

After reducing the emulator RAM to 768MB, I can rid off the above issue. However I cant see any devices connected in adb devices command. If you see the below log, it started and immediately stopped.

```
Building in workspace C:\Program Files\Jenkins\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\AVD_Manager_Start_Emulator
[android] Failed to create file or directory: C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.android
[android] Using Android SDK: C:\Users\Divakar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
$ C:\Users\Divakar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe start-server
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5813
* daemon started successfully
$ C:\Users\Divakar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe start-server
[android] Snapshots are enabled, but cannot be used as they are not supported by the current SDK Tools
[android] Starting Android emulator
[android] Erasing existing emulator data...
$ C:\Users\Divakar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/emulator/emulator.exe -ports 5754,5755 -report-console tcp:5838,max=60 -avd Pixel_2_Pie_9.0 -wipe-data -no-window
Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
dsound: Could not set cooperative level for window 0000000000000000
dsound: Reason: An invalid parameter was passed to the returning function
audio: Could not init `dsound' audio driver
emulator: WARNING: Requested adb port (5755) is outside the recommended range [5555,5586]. ADB may not function properly for the emulator. See -help-port for details.
[android] Emulator reported that the console is available on port 5,754
[android] Waiting for emulator to finish booting...
$ C:\Users\Divakar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe -s emulator-5754 wait-for-device shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
[android] Emulator reported that the startup process is ''
$ C:\Users\Divakar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe -s emulator-5754 wait-for-device shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
[android] Emulator reported that the startup process is ''
$ C:\Users\Divakar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe -s emulator-5754 wait-for-device shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
[android] Emulator reported that the startup process is ''
$ C:\Users\Divakar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe -s emulator-5754 wait-for-device shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
[android] Emulator reported that the startup process is ''
$ C:\Users\Divakar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe -s emulator-5754 wait-for-device shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
[android] Emulator reported that the startup process is ''
$ C:\Users\Divakar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe -s emulator-5754 wait-for-device shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
[android] Emulator reported that the startup process is ''
$ C:\Users\Divakar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe -s emulator-5754 wait-for-device shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
[android] Emulator reported that the startup process is ''
$ C:\Users\Divakar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe -s emulator-5754 wait-for-device shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
[android] Emulator reported that the startup process is ''
$ C:\Users\Divakar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe -s emulator-5754 wait-for-device shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
[android] Emulator reported that the startup process is ''
$ C:\Users\Divakar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe -s emulator-5754 wait-for-device shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
[android] Emulator reported that the startup process is ''
$ C:\Users\Divakar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe -s emulator-5754 wait-for-device shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
[android] Emulator reported that the startup process is ''
$ C:\Users\Divakar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe -s emulator-5754 wait-for-device shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
[android] Emulator reported that the startup process is ''
$ C:\Users\Divakar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe -s emulator-5754 wait-for-device shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
[android] Emulator reported that the startup process is ''
$ C:\Users\Divakar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe -s emulator-5754 wait-for-device shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
[android] Emulator reported that the startup process is ''
$ C:\Users\Divakar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe -s emulator-5754 wait-for-device shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
[android] Emulator reported that the startup process is ''
$ C:\Users\Divakar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe -s emulator-5754 wait-for-device shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
[android] Emulator reported that the startup process is ''
$ C:\Users\Divakar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe -s emulator-5754 wait-for-device shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
[android] Emulator reported that the startup process is ''
emulator: INFO: boot completed
emulator: Increasing screen off timeout, logcat buffer size to 2M.
emulator: Revoking microphone permissions for Google App.
$ C:\Users\Divakar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe -s emulator-5754 wait-for-device shell getprop dev.bootcomplete
[android] Emulator reported that the startup process is '1'
$ C:\Users\Divakar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe -s emulator-5754 shell logcat -v time
[android] Emulator is ready for use (took 283 seconds)
[AVD_Manager_Start_Emulator] $ cmd /c call C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\jenkins8495526174755772173.bat

C:\Program Files\Jenkins\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\AVD_Manager_Start_Emulator>exit 0 
[android] Stopping Android emulator
emulator: Saving state on exit with session uptime 257552 ms
[android] Archiving emulator log
$ C:\Users\Divakar\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe kill-server
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Could this help you? https://github.com/jenkinsci/android-emulator-plugin/pull/27

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Unfortunately not as I am using very latest plugins. I have dig into further and got few updates. Will update my question with latest findings..

Comment: can some help on this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. Please find the steps that I have followed

1. Uninstall Jenkins
2. Install war file

Thats all

Comment: please let me know if you will uninstall jenkins and install again then what the build that you have already created?
simply you are saying to that uninstall and re install will solve this issue?